# how to assign id mapped entity

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

```
*@Entity
@Table(name = "model_data")
public class ModelData {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "diagram_id")
    private DiagramEntity diagram;
    //Getter Setter
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "diagram")
public class DiagramEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @JsonProperty(value = "class")
    private String aciklama;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "diagram")
    private Set<ModelData> modelData;

//Getter Setter 
}*
```

DiagramEntity has manytoone relation with modeldata entity. Then I post

```
*{
    "modelData": [
        {
            "diagram": null,
        }
    ],
}*
```

via postman, DiagramEntity id is automatically updated but I cannot assign id to modelData entity and cannot save to database. what should I do?

Comment: How do you map the Json to the entities?

Comment: I write service but I dont know exactly how to map JSON to my entities

Comment: @SimonMartinelli thank you for reply. After your question, I found solution.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution for my problem. I streamed every object and mapped to my entities in the my controller class.

```
public DiagramEntityDto saveOrUpdate(@RequestBody DiagramEntityDto dto) {
        try {
            dto.getModelData().stream().map(a -> 
                 this.modelDataService.saveOrUpdate(a)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
            return this.diagramService.saveOrUpdate(dto);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```